# Why can we use matrices to represent elements of polynomial vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

I think I understand the concept of the polynomial vector space over a field F (set of polynomial functions whose coefficients are part of F), but when describing a transformation from one polynomial vector space to another —- why are we allowed to use matrices to describe that? Matrices aren’t elements of the polynomial vector space, but it is its own vector space right? For example, when describing the transformation matrix for the linear transformation that is the derivative of a polynomial, we have a matrix of coefficients and then multiply that by whatever input column coefficient vector we have that represents a polynomial, but that column vector itself is not part of the polynomial vector space so how do we know it describes a polynomial in the first place?

Comment: The matrix is a set of coefficients *with respect to a particular choice of input and output bases*. Once you have chosen a basis for the domain and codomain, the linear transformation is completely characterized by the coefficients.

Comment: @Bungo So, you are saying that even though the matrix is its own vector space, we can use it for other vector spaces as well? Why can we do that?

Comment: @Zest Sorry, I'm not sure I understood what you were trying to say, if you could rephrase it or elaborate more, that would clear things up for me. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the vector space $P_{n - 1}(k)$ of polynomials of degree $\leq n - 1$ with coefficients in the field $k.$ Observe that the standard basis of $P_{n - 1}(k)$ is $\mathscr B = \{1, x, x^2, \dots, x^{n - 1}\}.$ (Use the derivative to prove that these are linearly independent.) Consider a linear operator $T : P_{n - 1}(k) \to P_{n - 1}(k).$ Given any polynomial $p(x)$ in $P_{n - 1}(k),$ we can write $T(p(x))$ in terms of the basis $\mathscr B.$ Particularly, $$\begin{align*} T(1) &= a_{11} + a_{21} x + \cdots + a_{n1} x^{n - 1}, \\ \\
T(x) &= a_{12} + a_{22} x + \cdots + a_{n2} x^{n-1}, \\ &\phantom{\,\,} \vdots \\ T(x^{n-1}) &= a_{1n} + a_{2n} x + \cdots + a_{nn} x^{n - 1}, \end{align*}$$ from which we obtain an $n \times n$ matrix $A = [a_{ij}]_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$ with coefficients in $k.$ (Explicitly, $A$ is the matrix whose $j$th column is $T(x^{j - 1}).$) We refer to $A$ as the matrix of $T$ with respect to $\mathscr B.$

**Example.** Consider the vector space $P_2(\mathbb R)$ of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ with coefficients in $\mathbb R$ (the real numbers). Recall that the derivative satisfies $\frac d {dx} [C \cdot p(x)] = C \cdot p'(x)$ for all real numbers $C$ and $\frac d {dx} [p(x) + q(x)] = p'(x) + q'(x)$ for all polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x),$ hence differentiation is a linear transformation. By the Power Rule, we have that $\deg p'(x) = \deg p(x) - 1,$ hence the map $D : P_2(\mathbb R) \to P_2(\mathbb R)$ defined by $D(p(x)) = p'(x)$ is a linear operator. Considering that $$\begin{align*} D(1) &= 0, \\ \\ D(x) &= 1, \text{ and} \\ \\ D(x^2) &= 2x, \end{align*}$$ we find that the matrix of $D$ with respect to $\mathscr B = \{1, x, x^2\}$ is given by $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: I understand what is being done here, but I'm still not sure why we're allowed to use a matrix A to describe the transformation with matrices having their own vector space

Comment: Like we can't multiply matrices by polynomials because they're in different vector spaces

Comment: I fear you misunderstand. If the ground field of a matrix and a vector are the same and the dimensions match up (e.g., $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $v$ is an $n \times 1$ vectors), then $Av$ is another $n \times 1$ vector. Polynomials form a vector space (as you yourself admit) over any field. Vectors need not be in coordinates, but if you like, you can think of the polynomial $p(x) = 3 + 4x - 2x^2$ in $P_2(\mathbb R)$ as the coordinate vector $v = \langle 3, 4, -2 \rangle^t.$ So, if we compute $Av$ for the $A$ in our example, we obtain $w = \langle 4, -4, 0 \rangle.$

Comment: Considering $w = \langle 4, -4, 0 \rangle$ as a polynomial by using the basis $\{1, x, x^2\},$ we obtain $q(x) = 4 - 4x = p'(x),$ as desired.

Comment: Ahh yes, I think I am still stuck in thinking of coordinate vectors as legitimate vectors. Does the coordinate vector for the polynomial you gave as an example exist in a separate vector space over the same ground field as the coefficients of the polynomial?

Comment: Not really, no; it's just a different way of viewing the vector $p(x) = 3 + 4x - 2x^2.$ Unfortunately, matrices require some sort of coordinatization in order to make sense, but as you can see, the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq n - 1$ over a field $k$ can easily be coordinatized: the coordinate vector of $a_1 + a_2 x + \cdots + a_n x^{n-1}$ is simply $\langle a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \rangle.$ Of course, this implicitly relies on the choice of the standard ordered basis $\mathscr B = \{1, x, \dots, x^{n - 1}\},$ but something similar works for any basis.

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad I could help!

Comment: Does this also have to do with isomorphism between the matrix vector space and the polynomial vector space?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such isomorphism: the vector space of $n \times n$ matrices over $k$ has dimension $n^2$ (e.g., a basis consists of the matrices with $1$ in the $ij$th place and $0$s elsewhere), but the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $n$ has dimension $n + 1.$

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense! Thanks!